# SQL Server sum for distinct record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this(I hope you understand it)

```
ProductID    BoxNo     Qty   
   A         1          3
   A         1          3
   A         1          3
   B         1          2 
   B         1          2
   B         2          1
   C         1          1
```

As you can see, Product A, Box# 1 has a Quantity of 3 which then appears 3 times in the table, Product B, Box # 1 has a quantity of 2 and appears 2 times and so on...

I want my result to be like this

```
ProductID    Max(BoxNo)  Total
   A          1          3
   B          2          3
   C          1          1
```

Using this query

```
Select distinct productid, max(BoxNo), sum(qty) as Total from [Table1] group by productid order by productid
```

Results would be

```
ProductID    Max(BoxNo)  Total
   A          1          9
   B          2          5
   C          1          1
```

If you're wondering why I don't just use count it's because sometimes there will be a column with a quantity of 10 which only appears once, if I count that one it will be counted as 1 instead of 10

Comment: Plz elaborate the second line of the expected result.

Comment: If the Qty of two ProductID-BoxNO pairs are different, how do you know wich is the good value?

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I selected the max value of the Box No for Product B which is 2, the Total column shows the Total quantity of that product regardless of the Box number it's in

Comment: @AnkitBajpai No, A has a total quantity of 3 and it appears 3 times in the table, I want to get the total of that which is 3 but I get 9, Like in B I must get 3 since Box 1 contains 2 and Box 2 contains 1, but using sum will give me 5

Comment: See the sol. of @jpw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of this as if distinct is applied after your select. Your query (without the distinct):

```
 select pid, max(box), sum(qty) from t group by pid order by pid
```

results in 1 row:

```
 A             1           9
```

that is distinct wont have any effect at all. You can either apply the distinct before your aggregation as in:

```
select pid, max(box), sum(qty) from (
    select distinct pid, box, qty from t
) group by pid order by pid
```

or count using distinct:

```
select pid, max(box), sum(distinct qty) from t group by pid order by pid
```

Why do you have duplicate rows in your table?

Comment: +1 for the shorter solution, totally forgot that you can use distinct in aggregates lol.

Comment: Second query worked, the first one was giving me an incorrect syntax near the keyword group, I guess I should have explained why I had duplicate rows, there's actually another column which has a different value for each row

Comment: @sabre That sounds like you need to normalize your data.

Comment: For the first solution you might have to to supply an alias for the derived table, `select pid, max(box), sum(qty) from ( ... ) as t2 group by pid order by pid`. Not sure whether sqlserver requires that or not.

Comment: @Lennart kinda late but I just wanted to say the second query actually doesn't work properly, the first one did after adding an alias thanks, as for why the second query doesn't work, if I had Box 1, Box 2, and Box 3, with a quantity of 2, 2, and 5 respectively I would get a sum of 7 using the second query instead of a sum of 9

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this is what you want?

```
SELECT 
    ProductID, 
    MAX(BoxNo) AS MaxBoxNo, 
    SUM(Qty) AS TotalQuantity 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1) YourTable
GROUP BY ProductID
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/217e80/1)